# Ubuntu Freezing (Chrome Runs Out of Memory?)

Tags: 12.04, memory, google-chrome

My Ubuntu 12.04 freezes when I open quite a few windows. I use it at work with a dual desktop, so I usually use about 10 different tabs in two different Chrome applications. I assume Chrome runs out of memory, or is it my small Swap partition?

Comment: hardware config?

Comment: Run chrome from the command line, and see why it freezes.  If its out of memory it'll say so, but if you have a decent bit of memory plus swap, it may be hardware config.  But chrome eats up memory when you are using it like you do, so...

Comment: How much is your RAM and swap?

Comment: Processor Intel Core 2 Duo

Comment: OK AskUbuntu does not make it easy for me now. I wanted to add an image with my partitions and have no idea how. I have RAM of 2x1GB DDR2 and HD of 250 GB, with Vista and Ubuntu as dual boot. SWAP has  2 GB.

Comment: This happens to me all the time. Hit Ctrl + Esc, pages began to use too much RAM, so reload them: http://blog.burrowsapps.com/2012/11/ubuntu-purge-memory-on-google-chrome.html

Answer (score 2):

If Chrome really runs out of RAM, there are two simple options:

1. Add more RAM.
2. Open less tabs.

Another route it to reduce RAM consumption by other processes, for example, disable what's not used, or switch to XFCE or LXDE desktop environments.

Comment: Is there a way I can see if the problem is actually in the memory? Maybe the Plugins on Chrome are the cause? How can I tell?

Comment: The system monitor shows RAM usage, as well as swap. If the system starts to swap heavily, then yes, it's probably run out of RAM.

Comment: Thanks,Mike. I looked on the system monitor, before I open chrome, my system uses about 23% of memory and 0% of swap (swap not abailable) - after I open chrome, it uses on average 60% of memory. Does this indicate that the memory is the problem?

Comment: That's not necessarily a problem, as it depends on how much RAM there is. You should post the output of `free -m` for review. Use pastebin.com, if you can't add it the question.

Comment: total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2004       1873        131          0         35        597
-/+ buffers/cache:       1239        764
Swap:            0          0          0

http://pastebin.com/Kqt60dD8

Comment: That is not what I'd call critical, but it also shows that there is no swap partition (why not?), which might be a problem if the system tries to swap. You may need to experiment with lowering the swappiness, also, check the syslog after a freeze, or post it all to pastebin.

Comment: From the data that I've posted, can we conclude that the problem is actually the memory or we don't know that for sure? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you start swaping your computer will get slow, if you had too little swap, then it wouldn't freeze, instead using too much memory would trigger the kernels *Out Of Memory* killer, which would then kill the "*Baddest*" process. (usually your graphical server, or processes in chrome, which would result in the "sad tab" page, or Firefox.) It doesn't sound like you are running out of swap, most computers will get far too slow when they start using alot of swap.

Turning off javascript is a major move towards using less memory, but lots of pages wont work, NoScript for Firefox makes this more managable. Also, keep the number of open tabs low, and some sites (IME "Web 2.0" news sites like Huffington post are the worst) are much more performance hungry than others.

A good program to let you see what processes are running on your computer is `htop`, which you can install from the software center.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is known for using more memory than Firefox. Chrome is written with the assumption that people will happily buy more RAM and then they will want pages to load super-super fast. (And that this behaviour is preferable to using less memory and performing better with 200+ tabs.)

There are a number of extensions that help one "save tabs for later" like Too Many Tabs and TabCloud.

Another option is to open articles in `w3m` (a text-only browser which uses less memory).

HTH.

Comment: "Performing better" is not synonymous with "less memory".  On 11.10, at least, Chrome [is shown](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/chrome-17-firefox-10-ubuntu,3129-14.html) to use more memory than Firefox, but manage it better.

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh The OP speculated that his/her problem is that the computer runs out of memory. Hence "Performing better" is not necessarily the relevant question. Regarding your link: I don't think there is a uniform definition of "better". The OP may find with his/her browsing style that the results s/he cares about differ from the measurements at your linked site.